# Could not create schema and table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker

I faced with a weird behavior in the PostgreSQL database. I have the image in the Docker file that creates the database (here is the code of the Docker file):

```
  in_postgres:
      image: postgres:latest
      restart: always
      container_name: in_postgres
      hostname: in_postgres_hostname
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: in_postgres_user
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: in_postgres_password
        POSTGRES_DB: test_jdbc_sink_connector
      command: ["postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical"]
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "psql", "-U", "in_postgres_user", "-d", "test_jdbc_sink_connector", "-c", "SELECT 1"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      volumes:
        - ./dependencies/in_postgres_startup_insert.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/in_postgres_startup_insert.sql
```

As you see in this Docker file I use `in_postgres_startup_insert.sql` file.

Here is the code of the `in_postgres_startup_insert.sql` file:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_jdbc_sink_connector;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test_jdbc_sink_connector TO in_postgres_user;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS kafka;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA kafka TO in_postgres_user;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_jdbc_sink_connector.kafka.location (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    location_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    city VARCHAR(255),
    insertion_date TIMESTAMP
);
```

For some reason, I see only database: `test_jdbc_sink_connector` but not schema and table (they have not been created for some reason). I already tried different combinations inside the `in_postgres_startup_insert.sql` (with schema/without schema/tried to create a table inside the `public` schema), but the result is the same: no schema, no table.

Here is a screenshot of the DBeaver:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lRRk.png)

Maybe somebody could help. I don't understand why the table has not been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always first check the docker container logs if there's anything relevant there. `docker compose logs`.

Based on my test, the first problem in the log is:

```
ERROR:  database "test_jdbc_sink_connector" already exists
```

So if you get that, it means that since you already provided the table name in `POSTGRES_DB`, you can remove the db creation line from your sql.

Secondly, make sure you do full `docker compose down` before doing `docker compose up` if you keep doing changes to the init sql. Otherwise it sneakily fail because it will not re-execute the init sql and just go through:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```